# How to customized font style in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I wanted to customized the font style in my Fragment and it always force closing even if i already use view and getActivity() in my code. Here is my code

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.changeFontFragment, container, false);

    TextView place = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.place);

    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/RegencieLight.ttf");
    place.setTypeface(type);

    return rootView;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What error do you see in your logcat?

Comment: Try to use this library.  It's simple https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: Could you post the logcat output? There might be an exception which you might be missing. Look at [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) if you don't know what logcat is.

Comment: you can check : textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(textView.getContext()
                                                              .getAssets(),
                                                      fontFileName),
                             Typeface.NORMAL);

Answer (score 0):

I think capital letters are not allowed in resource file names. So try changing changeFontFragment layout file name to change_font_fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Official doc says :

> If you are using the Support Library APIs for the action bar, then you must use (or override) the **Theme.AppCompat** family of styles (rather than the Theme.Holo family) ... and each style property that you declare must be declared twice.

```
 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>

        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/action_background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

        <item name="background">@color/action_background</item>
         <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_title_color</item>
    </style>
```

for more info visit [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)